# Python win32com leer adjuntos en outlook

Tags: python

estoy haciendo un script que recorre la carpeta de entrada y subcarpeta de Outlook en búsqueda de un correo con un PDF adjunto.  El correo en cuestión siempre es el mismo y el pdf siempre tiene la misma estructura para leer los campos significativos.

La pregunta es, ¿se puede leer el contenido del fichero adjunto directamente al recorrer la Bandeja de entrada o la carpeta que se desee sin necesidad de descargar el fichero, o para leer el fichero adjunto hay que descargar el mismo?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a una carpeta local, en el disco, o al buzón remoto accedido por IMAP? ¿Cómo usas win32com para esta tarea?

Comment: Estoy leyendo los correos con PDF ajunto en la "Bandeja de Entrada" del Outlook instalado en mi portátil, por lo que sería en una carpeta local.

Me interesa saber si puedo leer el contenido del pdf adjunto sin necesidad de descargarlo.  Es decir, según voy encontrando correos (unos 3.500 correos en la bandeja) y contiene el pdf adjunto que quiero leer, que lo lea sin descargarlo.  Descargándolo puedo leerlo, pero quiero leerlo como adjunto en el propio correo.  ¿Es posible?

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo lo que pretendes. Si los correos ya están en tu disco, ya están descargados. No sé a qué te refieres entonces con "sin descargar" o "en el propio correo". Tampoco entiendo qué quieres decir con "leer". ¿Te refieres a mostrarlo en pantalla para que el usuario pueda leerlo? ¿A "extraerlo" del email para guardarlo aparte? ¿A analizar el contenido y por ejemplo convertirlo a texto? Quizás si muestras el código de lo que estás haciendo pueda entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Disculpar el retraso en responder.  Si entiendo que si estoy recorriendo la bandeja de entrada de Outlook, es que ya está en mi disco.  Me refiero a que si pretendo leer -que es el objetivo del script en python- un PDF adjunto en los correos, si puedo hacerlo desde el propio Outlook o tengo que descargarlo para que el script lo lea.  Ya tengo realizado algún script en python que lee pdf, pero no sé si en el caso de leer un PDF adjunto en un correo de Outlook, lo puedo leer directamente desde el correo o tengo que descargarlo a otra carpeta y desde allí realizar la lectura.  Saludos.